# Why is 'Ground' important?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding

I'm failing to understand why ground wires are important in electrical outlets.

- They don't protect me if I shove a knife into the outlet.
- Without a GFCI, the circuit doesn't "know" there is a problem.

When does a ground wire help me?

Comment: If you shove knives in electrical outlets, you won't be around to protect from faults very long anyway. But the code folks do have and require tamper resistant outlets to try and prevent that, but I'm sure you'll find an older one you can get your knife into somewhere, or shove harder than a child and manage to break the part protecting you.

Comment: This is a fallacy.  The fallacy is that you are cherry-picking examples where grounds don't make a difference, and not thinking about examples where ground does make a difference.

Comment: First stop: why is there ground at all (there was a time when ground was not required at the panel. Hilarity ensues under many situations resulting in major damage to homes when the power company messes up). Second step: understand grounding and bonding, and realize that the green wire on a metal-bodied appliance is for bonding, to keep it at ground potential.

Comment: Too short for an answer, but check the "TN-S" (with ground) vs "TN-C" (without dedicated ground) table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthing_system#Comparison

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Answers provided so far are good, but I would like to add another very important aspect of ground.

When looking at neutral vs ground, the question you ask is very natural. After all, both ground and neutral may be connected back to the same grounding bus at the circuit box.

However, there is a very important distinction! Neutral is designed to carry current while ground is not. Neutral completes the circuit, and is not a "safe" wire since the voltage will travel from the hot wire, through the load (appliance, light, whatever), then back to ground via the neutral wire.

Ground, on the other hand, is designed to never be energized under normal conditions. It is a safety wire, that should NEVER be used as part of the circuit. By design, if the hot wire ever comes in contact with ground, the circuit breaker will immediately trip to de-energize the line.

Any time metal is exposed on an appliance or fixture, the metal will be connected to the ground wire. This ensures the metal never becomes energized, potentially causing electrocution.

GFCI is a different subject, which really has nothing to do with the ground wire. Ground wire WILL protect you against scenarios where the hot wire comes into direct contact with any (grounded) metal. But if the hot wire comes into contact with water it may or may not trip a standard breaker. This is because water, while a potential conductor of electricity, is not a perfect conductor. The circuit breaker may simply view the water as "normal load". GFCI's are specifically designed to protect in these type of situations. This is why GFCI is required for outlets in areas where water is expected, but not for areas expected to stay dry.

Comment: GFCI measures the electrical potential difference between hot and neutral. The ground wire is certainly relative here. If there is a short to ground in the wiring or in the device in use (even outside of a water scenario), the GFCI will trip as there are more Amps being carried along the hot than there is the neutral. Also, GFCIs are required in more spaces than just wet ones. Garages, unfinished basement areas are examples.

Comment: Most garages and unfinished basements also have the potential to become wet at times. :)

Comment: @stevieb GFCI does NOT measure potential difference (voltage) it measures **current** in both hot and neutral conductors, and if there is a mismatch (>5 mA for USA/Canada branch circuits, >30Ma for the "whole-house" units common in other parts of the world) between current going out and current coming back, it trips.

Comment: If a neutral wire accidentally gets disconnected, it becomes hot.

Comment: @Ecnerwal correct but your correction has a typo (it should be 30**mA**)

Comment: Would ground not be considered part of the circuit with say a nema 5-50?

Comment: @jesse_b You mean because it is part of the plug, or else why?

Comment: @user253751 because there is no neutral.  It's 2 hots and a ground.

Comment: @jesse_b Google tells me that NEMA 5-50 is a 50-amp 120V socket which is rarely used. But anyway, if you did have a 240V circuit with two hots, that is still a circuit and the ground is still just for grounding. Some naughty appliances try to cheat by using ground as neutral. They are naughty. They're not allowed to do that. The correct solution is to upgrade it to a 4-pin socket with hot+hot+neutral+ground

Comment: @user253751 ah you're right I'm thinking of 6-50

Answer (score 17):

Ground wires in receptacles perform two basic functions:

- Path for surge protection and other things that are *not* part of the regular circuit
- Complete the circuit in certain fault situations

I would generally consider the 2nd of these the most important.

Consider a typical metal case appliance (washing machine, dryer, oven, etc.) or a metal junction box. If there is a fault where a hot wire touches the metal case, without a ground wire the circuit is *not* completed but the case is now "hot". If someone then touches the case, some of the electricity may flow through them to the actual ground (the earth beneath their feet) and kill them. Really.

If that same appliance or metal box has the metal connected to a proper ground (wire or metal conduit going back to the main panel neutral/ground bond) then the circuit is completed and, assuming the fault results in overcurrent (e.g., a "short circuit") then the breaker trips quickly.

A GFCI will effectively take care of most of these situations, and in fact do so faster than a regular circuit breaker in many cases. However, ground connections have been around for a long time compared to GFCI, and GFCI is still relatively expensive to install, particularly on high current (30A or more) 240V circuits. So GFCI as an alternative will work, except for the surge protection issue, and in fact is approved as a substitute when a ground wire is not available/practical.

As far as the "shove a knife in the outlet" problem. That is a little different and has multiple solutions:

- If the knife is shoved in the neutral pin, there is no issue anyway.
- New 15A/20A receptacles are generally required to be tamper-resistant, to help prevent exactly that problem, at least for unintentional situations (e.g., small children) - if someone is really determined, then...
- [Darwin Awards](https://darwinawards.com/)

Comment: +1 for the Darwin Awards! :)

Comment: My parents could attest to that it was one of my fun things to do.

Comment: Grounding will probably never go away. That said, AFCI and GFCI breakers have sort of rendered grounding obsolete.  The 2020 NEC code requires just about EVERYTHING to be GFCI protected.   Just as an aside:  GFCI breakers provide both GFCI protection and over current protection.  A common misunderstanding is GFCI OUTLETS (not breakers) **DO NOT**  provide over-current protection, but presumably the circuit is properly protected by the breaker feeding it.

Comment: @George I wouldn't say that.  If ground were simply gone, and someone touched a GFCI protected hot, what would their reference be? Ground is gone, so what else is around in abundance that they might contact?  In a plastic house with plastic pipes.  Well, GFCI protected neutral is around a lot.  So now their fault presents as a hot-neutral load, and the GFCI goes "cool, cool".

Comment: @George Harper is correct (as usual). The exception would be "through person to physical ground through the feet", which would trip GFCI but not trip a simple breaker (because of high resistance, relatively speaking). There is another use case: damaged wires (nail or mouse) between regular breaker and first GFCI protected receptacle - GFCI *can't* catch that because it is before the GFCI, but ground (e.g., hot to bare ground wire or to metal junction box or conduit) will trip the breaker. That is more of a fire safety issue than people safety because people don't (usually) touch those places.

Comment: A couple of good points by Harp and Manass....    But... and here's the big but:  GFCIs measure the load and neutral, if it's not exactly the same, it trips, regardless of a ground. It's code legal to install GFCIs w/o ground, provided it is labeled "GFCI protected, no equipment ground.   Manass.... In your example, if it was a GFCI breaker (not outlet), it would certainly catch that instantly.   ....Don't get me wrong on this, I have no issue with grounding, it's kind of a belt and suspenders approach. BTW, when I wired my son's new house we went will all DUFI breakers (GFCI and AFCI).

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson You are 100% correct. My point is based on GFCI protection *often* being at the receptacle or first point-of-use rather than at the breaker. There are a number of reasons for that on typical 120V 15A/20A circuits - much lower cost (which is why my electrician likes it), ability to retrofit to older circuits (which is how I have it on my bathrooms even before my recent-almost-complete-hopefully-next-Monday panel replacement), ability to add on new circuits even if old panel can't take GFCI breakers (which is how my kitchen renovation 20+ years ago got GFCI). New where AFCI

Comment: (which in most cases **is** best done at the breaker) is being done as well, AFCI+GFCI at the breaker makes a bit more sense. Exception even then is going to be GFCI in kitchens and bathrooms - due to the frequency (relatively speaking - in my case only a few times over 20 years, but still...) of GFCI trips due to water in kitchen/bathrooms having convenient easy obvious reset instead of "what just happened, why'd the breaker trip" will likely lead many to prefer GFCI/receptacle even with newer panels and even when cost is a non-issue (and for most of us, cost **is** an issue).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Yeah, GFCI breakers are about double the price of GFCI outlets, agreed there.   My son wanted the best, latest protection so that's why we went in all DUFIs (Ground fault, over current protection, series and parallel arc fault) all in one breaker.  Also I went with a PON (plug on neutral) panel which made for a super clean install, none of those piggly whites cluttering everything up.   I did mention nuisance trips would mean a trip to the breaker panel, rather than right where the GFCI outlet tripped, but he was OK w/that.

Answer (score 14):

### GFCI and RCD only detects current movement to a 3rd current path.  *What did you do with it?*

By abolishing grounds you now have nowhere for fault current to go.  So an appliance develops a hot-chassis fault, and the chassis is energized at line voltage. "Who cares," you say.  "Anyone who touches it is now biased at GFCI-protected line voltage and that's that. They won't get shocked, because there's nothing for them to be shocked *in relation to*.  This house doesn't have grounds and pipes are plastic."  Very clever.

*But because that never happens, **this means, the faulty appliances are rarely detected and simply left to fester**. The installed base will accumulate many appliances with longstanding faults*.  And so what?  Even if every appliance had a hot-chassis fault and you found a way to touch 4 of them at once, they're at the same potential so again nothing to be shocked *in relation to*. **Right?**

Well... don't you think it's a coincidence that they are all *hot-chassis* faults and there are no *neutral-chassis* faults?   Now what happens? One hand on GFCI-protected hot, and the other hand on GFCI-protected neutral.

***Whoops!***

The GFCI will only see a normal hot-neutral load.  The GFCI will not trip and the person will die.

So you see, you really need a 3rd "external to GFCI" current path *to be in the ecosystem* for GFCI protection to be meaningful.

You may not realize you want this, but you *want* swift detection and elimination of faulting appliances.  That's not going to happen without grounds.

Comment: I wonder what difficulties there would be with designing GFCI receptacles for "no equipment ground" scenarios which would monitor the third prong of installed plugs for inappropriate continuity to hot or neutral and trip if such continuity is detected, even if no grounding means is available?  That would seem better than simply leaving the pin floating, as appears to be current practice.

Answer (score 5):

Grounded outlets are so you can plug in appliances with a three prong, grounded, plug.

How it was explained to me 62 years ago. A plumber is under the sink drilling some holes to support pipes. It's cramped so he's holding on to some drain pipe for support. The hot wire from the drill breaks away from the switch of the drill and comes in contact with the drill metal housing. Voltage and current from the drill housing goes through the plumber to the grounded pipe. Dead plumber. If the drill housing had a ground wire, the breaker/fuse would have tripped/blown then the hot wire came in contact with the metal housing of the drill. Live, scared plumber.

Comment: We also had the three prong adapters, the ones where you hope the screw holding the face plate on, went to ground.

Comment: Moral of story - don't use 62yo drills. Most these days are double insulated, or better still, most are battery operated,  obviating the problem, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Ground is not perfect, but is there in case the metal case/housing of a device/appliance comes in contact with a hot/live wire.

No ground so when you touch the appliance you are touching live power.

All you have to do is also touch something that goes to ground(sink/faucet) and the power goes though you at least causing bad hurt/burns, possible death.

With ground, when the hot/live wire touches the metal housing, it will trip the breaker and you only miss having toast.

GFCIs do this much better in that they will trip if only a tiny amount of power goes where it is not suppose to, so the most you would feel is a tiny spark like static electricity.

Usually if you are not touching something that goes to ground, putting one knife into a outlet will probably not do anything to you.  Trying the same with a light socket if much different and hope your breaker works.

Answer (score 2):

There are some great answers here which cover the key points comprehensively, but I just want to make one extra point.

Two ends of a wire will always have (almost) the same voltage. If you take a wire and connect one end to ground, the other end of the wire will always have the same voltage as ground. If you connect the other end to the metal case of an applicance, the case will always have the same voltage as ground.

Whatever else you connect to that case -- whether it touches a live wire, neutral, whatever -- the case will always have the same voltage as ground. It has to, because it's physically wired to the ground.

If someone touches a metal case which has the same voltage as ground, while standing on the ground, then they are not going to get electrocuted.

The ground connection is there to ensure that, *whatever else happens*, whatever else comes into contact with that metal case, and whatever else goes wrong, someone cannot get electrocuted by it.

The fact that fuses blow and GFCIs trip if a live wire ends up coming into contact with a grounded metal case is great. However, the key takeaway is that by physically wiring your metal case into the ground, you make sure that someone cannot get electrocuted by touching the case.

Comment: Interesting answer. What happens if I'm holding onto the appliance when the housing "goes hot"? In a GFCI scenario, I would receive a *small-lived* shock (maybe non-noticed, but still existing nonetheless). Would any shock be mitigated through the ground housing, and trip the breaker, all without giving me any shock at all?

Comment: Theoretically, no. If you put a resistor (i.e. the human) and a zero-resistance wire (i.e. the ground connection) in parallel, the resistor will see no voltage across it, and there will be no current through it. In practice, the ground wire will have a small resistance / inductance, and the human may have a small amount of capacitance, meaning that a small amount of current may go into/through the human. I can't say I've ever attempted this to see whether it's noticeable however!

Comment: In contrast to the scenario you described however, almost all of the current required to trip the GFCI will go through the ground wire rather than the human, so the effect (if any) will be significantly less.

Comment: to specify, I was referring to a GFCI "no equipment ground" scenario, vs the grounded appliance scenario. So from what I understand, given a "no equipment ground" I would still receive a small shock, but from grounding I would receive theoretically no shock

Answer (score 0):

You're ignoring faults such as where a hot live wire goes loose and touches the metallic case of an appliance.

But my understanding is that even if you did not use ground to re-direct fault currents, ground is required for safety.

Since the electrical grid is very expansive it intercepts a lot of charge moving between the earth and atmosphere and this can cause the common mode voltage that the hot and neutral share rise dangerously above the potential of the Earth (which is the potential you are probably near). I suppose the most obvious example is if somewhere in the grid gets struck by lightning.

So things like giant sparks might jump out at you when you reach for the light switch or electrical socket.

I'll have to verify this though.

Comment: This is why we bond neutral to the ground. It’s not why we then bring ground to every receptacle/load.

Comment: @nobody Hmmm I suppose the OP did elaborate beyond the question title and ask why ground is important in electrical outlet rather than simply why it is important. However, it's also very possible that OP worded it that way because it never even occurred to him that ground had a purpose beyond that of the outlet